# How do you use a var in the url of window.open in js

Tags: javascript

I'm editing the code of a omegle ip tracker geo locator thing and I'm trying to make it use a better geolocator / ip locator "whatismyipaddress.com" and in the URL it uses there ip so I'm trying to do like: "window.open("whatismyipaddress.com/ip/{ip}") but when I use it in omegle it opens the whatismyipaddress.com/ip but then it has like %b23 or something weird. Any fixed?

```
    Original Code: <https://pastebin.com/yPM2nDp4>

    Edited Code: <https://pastebin.com/iUeV0F6S>
```

Thx! for any replies

Comment: what is the value of -> {ip} when you make request to whatismyipaddress.com/ip/{ip}.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question. We shouldn't have to go off site just to review your issue. Questions should be self contained

Comment: @AnshulRasiwasia its a regular ip. ex: 42.00.21.65

Answer (score 1):

it should be like:

```js
window.open(`https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/${ip}`)
```

`ip` value is retrieved from the lexical scope. In your code, you use a missing form of the template string (literal)